# Apply between function over a matrix by using lower bound and upper bound vectors

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame composed of numeric values. I calculated the standard deviation  and mean for each column and created `Upper_Bound` and `Lower_Bound` vectors as follows:

```
std_devs = apply(exp_vars[,sapply(exp_vars,is.numeric)], 2, sd)
means = apply(exp_vars[,sapply(exp_vars,is.numeric)], 2, mean)
Upper_Bound = means + 3*std_devs
Lower_Bound = means - 3*std_devs
```

Now i want to detect the rows that has at least one value that does not fall between the relevant upperbound and lowerbound. For example a value in column j must be equal or greater than Lower_Bound[j] and equal or smaller than Upper_Bound[j], if at least one value in a row i violates this condition I want to save the index of that row (I also have row names, saving row names would be fine too.) What I want to obtain is a vector of indices (or row names) that shows all rows which violate the rule. I tried the following:

```
outliers = apply(my_data ,1, between(x,Lower_Bound, Upper_Bound,incbounds = TRUE))
```

But i guess it was too much to expect between to automatically go over every value in a row and compare them with the relevant bounds. This was my second hopeless attempt that did not work:

```
outliers = apply(exp_vars_numeric,1, apply(x,2,between(x,Lower_Bound, Upper_Bound, incbounds = TRUE)))
```

I know that i can do it with a for loop but i am hoping for a more efficient solution. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider keeping everything in one data frame by adding lower and upper bound columns with help of `ave()` for inline aggregation of `sd` and `mean`. Then run conditional `ifelse()` for the flagging of such rows.

```
num_cols <- sapply(exp_vars,is.numeric)
num_names <- colnames(exp_vars)[num_cols]

means <- sapply(exp_vars[,num_cols], function(x) ave(x, FUN=mean))
std_devs <- sapply(exp_vars[,num_cols], function(x) ave(x, FUN=sd))

exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_lower")] <- means - 3*std_devs
exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_upper")] <- means + 3*std_devs

# CONDITIONALLY ASSIGN FLAG COLS
exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_flag")] <- ifelse(exp_vars[,num_names] >= exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_lower")] &
                                                exp_vars[,num_names] <= exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_upper")], 1, 0)    
# ADD ALL FLAG COLS HORIZONTALLY
exp_vars$index <- ifelse(rowSums(exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_flag")]) > 0, row.names(exp_vars), NA)

exp_vars[is.na(exp_vars$index), ]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This works well except for one little detail. I want to find the columns that has at least one 0-flag but this codes finds the ones that has at least one 1-flag. Thus i changed the last two lines like this:           
`num_cols_num = sum(num_cols)
exp_vars$index <- ifelse(rowSums(exp_vars[,paste0(num_names, "_flag")]) < num_cols_num, row.names(exp_vars), NA)
outliers_index = na.omit(exp_vars$index)`

Comment: Sounds good! Glad you are able to adapt solution to final needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to include a small example of how your data looks like so that it is easier for us to respond to your question :) I generated data.frames based on your description, and it seems that the following solves your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=c(5:14))
ncols <- ncol(df)
bounds <- data.frame(lower=seq(.5,5,.5),upper=seq(6.5,11,.5))
one_plus_fall_outside <-   sapply(1:nrow(df),
         function(i) 
           sum(between(df[i,],bounds$lower[i],bounds$upper[i]))/ncols<1
         )  
which(one_plus_fall_outside)
```

you can check if this works well by looking at all the columns together:

```
cbind(df,bounds,one_plus_fall_outside)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this code works well but it is not exactly the answer to my question. It assigns a different upper & lower bound for each row, whereas it should have been doing it for each column. For instance, ''column a'' should have one lower_bound and one upper_bound and each value in ''column a'' should be compared to those bounds. You don't need to fix the code tough, I used @parfait's suggestion and it works well. Thanks again.